# Why are both of my link green when they are visited?

Tags: html, css

I define a css file my_style.css and use it in my page.

```css
body {
  background-color: linen;
}
.myClass1 a:link,
a:visited {
  color: orange;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.myClass2 a:link,
a:visited {
  color: green;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <a class="myClass1" href="http://www.youtube.com">Link1</a>
  <a class="myClass2" href="http://www.youtube.com">Link2</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Why are both links green?

Comment: probably because of `,a:visited {` - add `.myClass1` (or 2) before each `a:visited`

Comment: The selector you wrote after the `,` is actually targeting all the `a` tags and not a specific `a` tag with that class name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both links are green because:

```
.myClass2 a:link,a:visited { /* foo */ }
```

reads as:

```
.myClass2 a:link { /* foo */ }
a:visited { /* foo */ }
```

and not as:

```
.myClass2 a:link { /* foo */ }
.myClass2 a:visited { /* foo */ }
```

You need to put the *full* selector in each part of the group.

```
.myClass2 a:link,
.myClass2 a:visited { /* foo */ }
```

---

Additionally, since the links themselves are members of the class, you don't want the descendant combinator in there.

```
a.myClass2:link,
a.myClass2:visited { /* foo */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the class selectors before the `a:visited` selectors

```
 a.myClass1:link,  a.myClass1:visited{
    color: orange;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

 a.myClass2:link,  a.myClass2:visited{
    color: green;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying stiles to `a:visited`, two times. The first time you're setting `color: orange`, the second one `color: green`.

Obviously both links are already `visited` since both are the same.

CSS stands for "cascading style sheets", that essentially means that the last properties override the first ones.

Your confusion might be in regards of how the `,` (comma) works. It means that the styles are to be applied to both selectors (what's before and what's after the comma).

Also, on your CSS the classes are applied to a parent of the `a` tag instead to the `a` tag itself. Here's an approach to a solution (since I don't know what you're trying to achieve:

```
/* this will apply to all <a> tags with class myClass1 */
a.myClass1 {
    color: orange;
}

/* this will apply to all <a> tags with class myClass2 AND to all visited a tags even if they are of class myClass1  */
a.myClass2,
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* This is so you don't write the same twice (DRY principle) */
a.myClass1,
a.myClass2 {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Essentially on your posted HTML, both links will be green. If you change one of them to a page you haven't visited, it will be orange.

Answer (score 0):

your current css of:

```
.myClass1 a:link,
a:visited {
  color: orange;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.myClass2 a:link,
a:visited {
  color: green;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

reads as the following:

for `myClass1`'s descendant `a` anchor tag that hasn't been visited (`link`), and for `a` anchor tag that has been `visited` make text color `orange` and make its left margin `40px`.

then for `myClass2`'s descendant `a` anchor tag that hasn't been visited, and for `a` anchor tag that has been `visited`, make the text color green and make its left margin `40`px;

as the others have said before, the `, a:visited` css is changing all the anchor tags to green because css applies its styles top down and green is the last reference of the element type.

you have to reference the full selector.  that being said, the previous answers include the descendant selectors (which will not work) since the anchor element is the same as the class element.  therefore something like this is what you're looking for

```css
body 
{
    background-color: linen;
}

a.myClass1:link, a.myClass1:visited{
    color: orange;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

a.myClass2:link, a.myClass2:visited{
    color: green;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a class = "myClass1" href = "http://www.youtube.com">Link1</a>
<a class = "myClass2" href = "http://www.youtube.com">Link2</a>
```

by not leaving the space between `a` and `.Class1`, the css denotes that they are the same element (versus the space in between them denoting descendant of)

hope this helps